# Problem with a DHT11 Temperature & Humidity sensor

Tags: sensors, temperature-sensor, code-review

I'm new in the Arduino world and today i was trying to make a simple program to show the temparature an humidity with this sensor. I made a circuit following one tutorial and nothing happend, **the result was Temperature: 0 Humidity: 0.** 
My question is, what is wrong? Probably the sensor is broken or the code is wrong.
*I also need to say that i use a 5K1 resistor in exchange of the 4.7K resistor and accidentally I connected the sensor without the resistance for a few seconds.*

**This is the code:**

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

int SENSOR = 2;
int TEMPERATURE;
int HUMIDITY;

DHT dht(SENSOR, DHT11);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
TEMPERATURE = dht.readTemperature();
HUMIDITY = dht.readHumidity();
Serial.print("Temperature: ");
Serial.print(TEMPERATURE);
Serial.print(" Humidity: ");
Serial.println(HUMIDITY);
delay(1000);
}
```

**This is the circuit scheme:**

[image]

**This is a photo of the circuit and the sensor (probably damaged):**

[image]
[image]
[image]

***Thanks for your time and sorry for my bad english.***

Comment: Caution! Always inspect components before hooking up! I got a DHT11 sensor in a Kuman kit. I hooked it up per standard and ran the sketch. Getting 0s reported back I grabbed the sensor to check it was in the board properly and it was burning hot. On closer inspection the were marked ground-data-VCC. Sensor is pooched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the problem by **not using the resistor** and connecting it directly, I also had a problem with the sensor pins since some were badly connected, but it was also solved. **Now both sensors are working well** including the melted one. ***Thanks!***.[image]