# DHT11 sensor reporting all null values

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, temperature-sensor

I am using a DHT11 sensor attached to a NodeMCU ESP8266 to have a web server reporting the local humidity and temperature values. I don't have a resistor attached in the circuit, the DHT11 is directly connected to the NodeMCU board. Till yesterday, the setup was giving me correct values, but from today morning, I am getting all nulls from the sensor. Does this mean that the sensor is dead? Should I have had a resistor attached to the circuit to prevent this, or does that not make any difference?

EDIT:

Please consider my question before negative voting me. I considered this question:

[Problem with a DHT11 Temperature & Humidity sensor](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/47124/problem-with-a-dht11-temperature-humidity-sensor)

I have followed the circuit diagram as given in the following page:

https://www.electronicwings.com/nodemcu/dht11-sensor-interfacing-with-nodemcu

It's just that I am using a NodeMCU istead of an Arduino. Does that make my question unworthy of posting here? The problem is similar.

Comment: From your question it's not clear if you have the pure (blue) DHT11 sensor or a module with the 4pin sensor mounted on a small pcb with only 3 pins. (The only difference between the sensor and module is that the module will have a filtering capacitor and pull-up resistor inbuilt, and for the sensor, you have to use them externally ***if*** required.). Without measuring or swapping with a replacement known to function it's a guessing game.

Comment: Hi @LotPings, I have the 4 pin sensor, I have followed the circuit diagram as provided in the following page: https://www.electronicwings.com/nodemcu/dht11-sensor-interfacing-with-nodemcu